# how i can load an number in BP in assembly language

Tags: assembly

I have an question , please help me

:write the statement that perform

Load the number 7986 into BP(Base pointer).

Answer (score 0):

If a direct move is not possible, try

```
mov ax,10
push ax
pop  bp
```